# Use of implicit in method definition

Tags: scala, playframework

Taking a look at some sample code in the Play framework for Scala:

```
def show(ean: Long) = Action { implicit request =>
        Product.findByEan(ean).map { product => 
            Ok(views.html.products.details(product))
        }.getOrElse(NotFound)
    }
```

What is the job of `implicit request` in this particular use case? Can the method be written without it and if `request` is defined outside of the scope of this method (Which I believe it is anyway), can it not be referenced here? Not understanding what exactly it is doing here, so any insight would be great.